# Is there a more effective way to run a node.js file at startup? (Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-server-2012

As of now I have a `.bat` file in the Startup folder which runs the command

`START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\restAPI & node server.js"`

This works perfectly but, because I am running this on Windows Server 2012 I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. Preferably run it in a way where the user could not accidentally close the cmd window.

Comment: Sure, create a service and have it start automatically. you can even add in auto recovery so if it exits with an error status code it'l auto restart.

Comment: That's exactly what the Startup folder is for. There's also Task Scheduler. But all options are equally effective IMO. More effective how really?

Comment: @laggingreflex I was looking for a way where the user would not be able to accidentally close the cmd window.

Comment: I use nssm for creating windows services. No idea if it's the best option out there, but it works for me.

Comment: Using Task Scheduler you can create a task that runs in [the background.](http://google.com/search?q=task+scheduler+background). It doesn't show any window